# Can't use LINQ in a VB.NET ASPX file, even if I import System.Linq

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, webforms

I've run into this problem over and over again, and it's rather frustrating - if I have an ASPX file with VB code in it, I can't use LINQ in that VB code, even if I import `System.Linq`:

```
<% Page Language="vb" ContentType="text/html" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Linq" %>

<script runat="server">
    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim list As New List(Of String)
        ' populate list here
        list = list.OrderBy(Function(q) q).ToList() ' error BC30456: 'ToList' is not a member of 'IEnumerable(Of Object)'
End Sub
</script>
```

Why is LINQ not working? But if I make my own extension methods and import the appropriate namespace, they work. I can call LINQ extension methods in a VB class or module, or even in the code-behind VB file of an ASPX page, but if I try to do it in the ASPX page itself, in a `<% %>` block or a `<script runat="server">`, I get this error. So I don't think it's the language version setting of the project, since it does work in VB files and for my own custom extension methods. Is there a separate language version setting that applies to only ASPX pages? Either in Visual Studio or IIS?

Oh, I discovered something else interesting: `Enumerable.Empty` is not available either:

```
Dim seq As IEnumerable(Of Object) = Enumerable.Empty(Of Object) ' error BC30451: 'Enumerable' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

I know that `System.Linq.Enumerable` is where the LINQ methods are defined - why would this one class out of all of the .NET class library be unavailable in an ASPX file?

And if I fully qualify it:

```
Dim seq As IEnumerable(Of Object) = System.Linq.Enumerable.Empty(Of Object) ' error BC30456: 'Linq' is not a member of 'System'
```

So the entire `System.Linq` namespace does not exist?!

Comment: Is ````List(Of String)```` even defined?

Comment: Oh, you're right, I forgot to include the import statement for `System.Collections.Generic`. Let me go fix that.

Comment: That is strange.  I can run this code fine, but the only difference is my page declaration ````<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="_testSO.aspx.vb" Inherits="_testSO" %>```` - I wonder if by Inheriting the code-behind (even without any actual useful code in there) it picks up all the assemblies it needs.